# Gantt Chart Flex For 4.1 SDK

Tags: apache-flex

I need suggestion over which gantt chart should i use in my flex application.
It should not hamper the performance of my application as well it should not be slow.
Kindly suggest if any one has worked on or used gantt in the application

Answer (score 0):

I know only 2 Gantt Chart Libraries:

- http://www.gantt4flex.com/flower-platform/home-gantt4flex.html
- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/elixir/